# script that prints smallest and largest number from input

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a problem with this code because it puts "done"(phrase to end the loop) as smallest input

```
largest = None
smallest = None
NumList = []
while True:
         value = input("enter a number:")
         NumList.append(value)
         if value=="done":
             break
try: f = float(num)
except :
    print("Invalid input")


print("Maximum is",min(NumList))
print("Minimum is",max(NumList))
```

Comment: you can just move the lines that check break (if value == "done": break) to line before adding value to list (Numlist.append(value))

Comment: You're appending a string to the NumList list. Probably not what you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two mistakes:

1. When the user inputs `'done'`, you are appending `'done'` *before* checking whether it is `'done'`. So you have `'done'` in your list even though you don't need it.
2. Conversion of a string to a float is out of place.

The following is a working modification:

```py
nums = []
while True:
    val = input("Enter a number: ")
    if val == "done":
        break
    try:
        nums.append(float(val))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Invalid input: {val}")

print(f"Maximum is: {max(nums)}")
print(f"Minimum is: {min(nums)}")
```